# TFS2010 - Exclude specific files from merge

Tags: branching-and-merging

I have a simple branch plan with a main and a development branch. In the development branch I have beside the source code some documents related to the development process which should not be merged to the Main branch upon merging the latest version of development to main. Is it somehow possible to mark specific files or folders in the source control as 'ignore' for merging?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer is, if you don't want to version control the documents along with the code then move them out of the branch :-)

If you still want the documents to be near the code they describe, but you don't want them promoted between branches then you could try to cloak the folder(s) containing the documents in your workspace (the folder in the main branch) TFS will ignore the folder when it performs a merge.

e.g.

$/[TeamProject]/[DevBranch]/Docs --- (not cloaked, so you can check the docs in and out)

$/[TeamProject]/[MainBranch]/Docs --- (cloaked, merging at the root of the branch will ignore this folder)